# How to show a readonly row in a GridControl

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation

I want to show a readonly information in a row of a `GridControl`. At the moment I am defining a background lightgray and the image columns with opacity 0.5. But I wonder if there is a better way to show a readonly information. Maybe something to do with the foreground of the row? Maybe an icon to show that the row is not editable?
What do you do in these cases?

Update: Added a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could handle this design pattern like a disabled button.
A button you can't interact with is grayed out.
The same might go for your readonly row. You should go for the solid, unmoving look. Grayed out makes it look it's set in stone, solid and unmoving. In this case you just have to make sure it's still readable. Also, no hover states on the readonly row might work and active hover states on the editable rows.

If you're using edit buttons in rows that are editable, maybe just leaving out that button in the row will make it clear to the user the row isn't editable.

If this is not quite the answer you are looking for I would advice to add a screenshot or a mockup (the icon with the pencil in the rich edit toolbar). This way you can make it more clear how other rows are editable (by clicking the entire row or just an edit button).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Grayed out can be a problem because I want the user can read well then information. And with the grayed out effect maybe it's difficult to read. I add a screenshot to show you what I am doing. I want also to show a dark gray color when a readonly row is selected because next to the grid there is a DetailsView for the selected item.

Comment: Where do users have to click to edit a row?

Comment: The users change the state of the editable error through the icon. The Icon is a toggle three state button and values are Active, Ignore and Solved

Comment: I think you might need to go for different hover states for row color and cursor and just not showing icons for read only rows. That might be clear enough.